# parfor multi core processing matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function file that simulates a matrix A (size is 100*100) for 1000 time steps and generates final outcome as A_t1000 (size 100*100 matrix).

E.g. if A = 100*100 at t0 then A_t1= 100*100; A_t2=100*100; …….. A_t1000=100*100 matrix. Each with different values, So I can have multiple slices of A from A_t1 to A_t1000.

My script file iterates this process for 100 iterations. Script file calls this function  and generates final output matrix B_t1000 = A_t1000 * 100. B_t1000 is the final output matrix which contains 100 As. B_t1000 dimensions are 100*100*100. The starting input parameters for function file are provided at the start of script file.

I am trying to run this code this using ‘parfor’. The aim is to run each iteration independently in separate core and then gather them at the end to generate B. The current code  looks something like ---

```
iter=100; 
p=0.8;N=1200;
maxgen=1000;
d=0.01; 
evalues=(d/2):d:(1-d/2); 
cvalues=(d/2):d:(1-d/2); %% p, N are starting parameters 
[C,E]=meshgrid(cvalues,evalues); %% Starting 10,000 combinations 

B_t1000 = []; %% initializing B_t1000
B_t200= []; %% initializing B_t200

parfor k=1:iter  

A_t1000= zeros(length(evalues),length(cvalues)); %%initializing A_t1000
A_t200 = zeros(length(evalues),length(cvalues)); %%initializing A_t200
for i=1:length(evalues)
for j=1:length(cvalues)
    e=evalues(i); % starting point input for e for function file
    c=cvalues(j); % starting point input for c for function file
   [A_t1000, A_t200] = function (e,c,p,N,maxgen); %% calling a function to generate A_t1000 and A_t200           
end
end

B_t1000 (1:length(evalues),1:length(cvalues),k) = A_t1000;
B_t200  (1:length(evalues),1:length(cvalues),k) = A_t1000;
end
```

I get an error message-- "The variable B_t1000 in a parfor cannot be classified". It has something to do with independence and indexing issues I guess.

Can anyone help me to run this code using parfor?

Larger the 'Ne' and 'maxgen' parameters longer the time taken to run the code by only 'for' loop. Currently larger parameter is taking >30 hours to run without parfor. I want to reduce this time significantly using parfor.

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of your result to a cell array.

To initialize use:

```
B_t1000 = cell(1,iter); %% initializing B_t1000
B_t200= cell(1,iter); %% initializing B_t200
```

And then within the `parfor` loop do

```
B_t1000{k} = A_t1000;
B_t200{k} = A_t1000;
```

If you really need the results to be a 3D matrix, then convert them after the `parfor`.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and let you know how it works. I am currently running it by converting Bs as cell arrays. Hopefully it will significantly reduce run time.

Answer (score 0):

B_t1000 and B_t200 in your code are **sliced variables** in parfor loop. The issue with your code is that the loop-variable (k in your case) of parfor can only be used as the **first level** indexing, where you use it as **third level** indexing.

Please see the official MATLAB document:
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html

A quick fix for your code, change the initialization code to:

```
B_t1000 = zeros(iter,length(evalues),length(cvalues)); %% initializing B_t1000
B_t200= zeros(iter,length(evalues),length(cvalues)); %% initializing B_t200
```

And change the assignments in your parfor loop to:

```
B_t1000 (k,:,:) = A_t1000;
B_t200  (k,:,:) = A_t1000;
```

Now the parfor loop variable k is used as the first level indexing of B_t1000 and B_t200. You can also define B_t1000 and B_t200 as cell arrays. Sometimes it makes things easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and let you know how it works. I am currently running it by converting Bs as cell arrays. Hopefully it will significantly reduce run time.